# Why is MongoDB storage constantly increasing?

Tags: mongodb

I have a single-host database which grew up to 95% of disk space while I was not watching. To remedy the situation I created a process that automatically removes the old records from the biggest collection, so the data usage fell to about 40% of disk space. I figured I was safe as long as the data size doesn't grow near the size of preallocated files, but after a week I was proven wrong:

```
Wed Jan 23 18:19:22 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/xxx.101, filling with zeroes...
Wed Jan 23 18:25:11 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/xxx.101, size: 2047MB,  took 347.8 secs
Wed Jan 23 18:25:14 [conn4243] serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, middle of mem: 590, after mem: 590, after connections: 590, after extra info: 970, after counters: 970, after repl: 970, after asserts: 970, after dur: 1800, at end: 1800 }
```

This is the output of `db.stats()`: (note that the numbers are in **MB** because of scale)

```
> db.stats(1024*1024)
{
    "db" : "xxx",
    "collections" : 47,
    "objects" : 189307130,
    "avgObjSize" : 509.94713418348266,
    "dataSize" : 92064,
    "storageSize" : 131763,
    "numExtents" : 257,
    "indexes" : 78,
    "indexSize" : 29078,
    "fileSize" : 200543,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**Question:** What can I do to stop MongoDB from allocating new datafiles?

Running `repair` is difficult because I would have to install new disk. Would running `compact` help? If yes, should I be running it regularly and how can I tell when I should run it?

**UPDATE:** I guess I am missing something fundamental here... Could someone please elaborate on connection between data files, extents, collections and database, and how space is allocated when needed?

Comment: You may want to add some detail about what your app is doing. Mongo doesn't automatically free storage space when it is no-longer used. It will replace records in place in certain situations, but otherwise it will just consume more disk.

Comment: It is basically just writing log and chart data and removing it once it is too old. However, I can't use capped collections because I need to have control over how much data I purge and which data I want to remove.

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 2):

1. Upgrade to 2.2.2 - 2.2.0 has an idempotency bug in replication and no longer recommended for production.
2. See here for general info http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size
3. The only way to recover space back from mongodb is to either sync a new node over the network - in which case the documents are copied over the the new file system and stored anew without fragmentation. Or to use the repair command - but for that you need double the disk space that you are using on disk. The data files are copied, defragged and compacted and copied back over the original. The compact command is badly named and only defrags - it doesn't recover disk space back from mongo.
4. Going forward, use usePowerOf2Sizes command (new in 2.2.x) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/
   If you use that command and allocate say an 800 byte document, 1024 bytes will be allocated on disk. If you then delete that doc and insert a new one - say 900 bytes, that doc can fit in the 1024 byte space. Without this option enabled, the 800 byte doc might only have 850 bytes on disk - so when it's deleted and the 900 byte doc inserted, new space has to be allocated. And if that is then deleted you will end up with two free space - 850 bytes and 950 bytes which are never joined (unless compact or repair is used) - so then insert a 1000 byte doc and you need to allocate *another* chunk of disk. usePowerOf2Sizes helps this situation a lot by using standard bucket sizes.